# What is the right way to use the manhattan function described bellow?

Tags: python, nlp, distance

I find this module, that have some string similarity methods implemented, on github https://gist.github.com/StuartGordonReid/90c8301f9403707a22ff. I'm new to python and I'm having some troubles to use de manhattan_distance function. The code for the function is:

```
  def manhattan_distance(self, p_vec, q_vec):
    """
    This method implements the manhattan distance metric
    :param p_vec: vector one
    :param q_vec: vector two
    :return: the manhattan distance between vector one and two
    """
    return max(np.sum(np.fabs(p_vec - q_vec)), self.e)
```

But when a try to use this function (something like this)

```
t = similarity.Similarity(1)
t.manhattan_distance(np.array(["this is a testee"]), np.array(["this is a test"]))
```

or:

```
vector_one = ["this", "is", "a", "test"]
vector_two = ["this", "is", "a", "testee"]
t.manhattan_distance(vector_one, vector_two)
```

I get the following error:

TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S16') dtype('S16') dtype('S16')

Comment: Is it supposed to be applied on arrays of words? Because it works when used on lists of numbers.

Comment: You mean the manhattan function?

Comment: Yes. What makes you think from looking at that code that it accepts two strings as input?

Comment: That function is meant to be applied on vectors, not on strings. What is your expected output?

Comment: Instead of "this", "is", ..., try to use 1, 2 and 3, 4 :-)

Comment: If you want to compare strings, the [Levensthein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) usually does a good job.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already using it but I need to compare the ratio of the two methods